# Как решить задачу по теме "словари" в Python

Tags: python, словари

Дан словарь `{'class':{'student':{'name':'Mike','marks':{'physics':70,'history':80}}}}`. Выведите на экран имя студента и его оценку по истории

Не так давно начала учиться, поэтому кому-то этот вопрос покажется элементарным, но мне - нет. Пыталась добраться до значения "name" и "history" через квадратные скобки [], но выдает KeyError. Понимаю, что необходимо как-то распаковать вложенные списки, но как это сделать - не знаю

Мой код:

```
d = {'class':{'student':{'name':'Mike','marks'{'physics':70,'history':80}}}}

d1 = d['name']

print(d1)
```

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Задание 25.py", line 2, in <module>
    d1 = d['name']
KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Какие айтишники доброжелательные - слов нет) Спасибо, ребята!

Comment: в словаре d нет ключа name. Ключ name есть во вложенном словаре, который в свою очередь тоже является вложенным.

Comment: @alenanickolaeva, вы бы хотели, чтобы пилот самолета, в котором вы летите  не сам выполнял домашние задания во время учебы по пилотированию, а за него это делали бы другие? Или врач? ;) А вдруг вы в будущем будете софт для автопилота создавать? :-D

Comment: Прочитайте вот это https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html Желательно позапускайте все примеры самостоятельно.

Comment: @MaxU Достаточно продолжительный отрезок времени пыталась решить эту задачу самостоятельно, но поняв, что все, баста - не въезжаю, решила попросить помощи у более опытных товарищей. Все же это лучше, чем просто забить болт и двигаться к следующей теме)

Comment: @SergeiMalanin спасибо большое за совет. И на этой платформе, и на других смотрела информацию, пробовала писать, но все равно не получалось добиться верного результата. Уже подсказали, как верно - и решение оказалось достаточно простым)

Answer (score 6):

Как работает Ваш словарь? По принципу матрëшки. Сначала Вы открываете одну и там находиться другая, ещë одна и так далее... Следовательно, чтобы добраться до name нужно написать:

```
d['class']['student']['name']
```

Если вывести данное, то можно увидеть введя так:

```
d1 = d['class']['student']['name']
print(d1)
```

Вывод:

```
 Mike
```

Можете проверить) Таким же образом работайте с history) Также могу привести пример с играми, чтобы попасть к финальному боссу, то нужно выполнить уровни. Также здесь) Успехов)

Comment: Спасибо большое!! Действительно - решение верно:) Взаимно!

Answer (score 0):

Верный ответ:

```
d = {'class': {'student': {'name': 'Mike', 'marks': {'physics': 70, 'history': 80}}}}
d1 = d['class']['student']['name']
d2 = d['class']['student']['marks']['history']

print('Имя ученика: ', d1)
print('Оценка по истории: ', d2)
```